# Error in Swift SDWebImage

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, nsobject, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImage` in my Swift app to download images to my tableview but I'm getting a simple error that I don't know how to fix. I finished converting my project from Objective C to Swift.

Code I'm using

```
 let imgURL = (testObject.value(forKey: "testURL"))
 self.myImageView.sd_setImage((with: imgURL as! URL!), placeholderImage: UIImage(imageNamed: "no-image.png"))
 self.myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Error:

> Argument labels '(imageNamed:)' do not math any available overloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try correct naming for UIImage initializer, and improved cast to URL:

```
let imgURL = testObject.value(forKey: "testURL") as! URL
self.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: imgURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "no-image.png"))
```

But better, you can use an image literal for "no-image":

```
let imgURL = testObject.value(forKey: "testURL") as! URL
self.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: imgURL, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no-image.png"))
```

And best would be to avoid the forced unwrap.

```
let imgURL = testObject.value(forKey: "testURL") as? URL
self.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: imgURL, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no-image.png"))
```

*[update: after author claims that value is a String]*

If value of "testURL" is a String, then you can't unwrap it as an URL. This code may help:

```
let imgString = testObject.value(forKey: "testURL") as? String ?? ""
self.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imgString), placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no-image.png"))
```

Comment: It shows no error but the images are not showing up, the placeholder is. I used your 3rd code.

Comment: @BroSimple is your value stored as an URL? maybe "testURL" is a String? Maybe aznelite89 answer is better.

Comment: Yes, testURL is a string, not stored as an URL

Answer (score 0):

This might be a change with Swift 3, but it should be `UIImage(named: "no-image.png")`

Comment: That gives me an error saying - cannot downcast from 'Any' to a more optional type 'URL!' . What do you think?

Comment: I think you need to look into the SDWebImage framework. It could be you need `URL` instead of `URL!` or that their framework is using a different version of Swift than you are using, and they changed `AnyObject` to `Any` which has caused problems in my code.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me. 
Try this: -

```
self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: item.image!))
```

You need to cast the string to URL in order for this to work.